# does entity framework supports oracle database?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I am want to start a new project using entity framework 6. I have decided to use Database First approach. I want to know if it is possible to use Oracle database for my new project with entity framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of Entity Framework supporting Oracle.  It's the other way around.  Entity Framework supports any data source, as long as a provider is written for it.  You need to install an Oracle provider with EF support.  If I'm not mistaken, the latest version of ODP.NET, which is downloadable from Oracle, has EF support.  It will generate a model from a database but whether it will go the other way, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possible. And [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html) you can find a tutorial about it from Oracle .